# .Net Core 3.0 HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure When trying to add AddHostedService() in startup class

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm working with MVC application with VS 2019 using .NET Core 3.0 and I need to include Service worker in my app 
 After adding this line in my Startup class : 
[image] 

I got this error : 
 
[image]

 
I need to know if I can use a Service worked in my MVC application and how can I resolve this problem  .

Comment: You can use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler to help debug.  It looks like 1) your IP Address/Port is wrong 2) the service isn't listening (use from cmd.exe >Netstat -a on server to see the state or the IP/Port) 3) your port number is being blocked 4)  there is no route to the server from the client.

Answer (score 1):

There can be many reasons. Some suggest(ed in earlier versions of .NET Core) to change the Hosting model from In-process to Out-of-process, for example [this known issue](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/2.2/2.2-known-issues.md). You can read more about Hosting models [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-3.1#hosting-models). In your case it is probably something else.

Now there are some good examples from Microsoft how to implement hosted services written eg. [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/background-tasks-with-ihostedservice). But it is also important how (when) to register that service.

In my case the background service uses `IServiceProvider` depdendency injected in its constructor that's why it really did matter on which line i registered the service - probably due to some internal dependencies which i didn't really figure out. Registering in Program.cs like this solved my problem:

```
.ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddHostedService<YourAwesomeBackgroundService>();
    });
```

You can probably play around with the order of registrations (based on dependencies) in your `ConfigureServices` method in Startup.cs if you did it that way or try to remove some dependencies to figure out which causes the problem.

If this doesn't solve your problem i suggest to turn on some logging service since there must be some exceptions thrown.